# Uninstall a Package Installed With Curl

Tags: curl, meteor, iron-router

I installed the Iron Meteor framework using the Curl package manager for a group class project. The group has since decided to use another framework. I would like to purge the Iron Meteor framework from my Linux system but have been unable to find an uninstall command for Curl. The command to install it was found on the [Meteor Tips](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/getting-started/) web site:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Curl's *--help* hasn't relieved anything useful. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to remove meteor? Or iron-router package from meteor?

Comment: Iron router. I looks like the meteor I install in additional to the iron router can be simply deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a package from meteor project, either in command line or by deleting it from ./meteor/packages file.

So to remove iron:router just type in terminal:

```
meteor remove iron:router
```

Or find iron:router in your .meteor/packages file and simply delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You can uninstall meteor with the following commands

```
rm -rf ~/.meteor/

sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor
```

Official instructions at https://github.com/meteor/meteor (search for uninstall)

Comment: Note: This is not a one-size-fits-all approach for uninstalling all packages installed using curl. Check the package's documentation for instructions on uninstalling a specific package.